# What is the best way to answer [identify-this-movie] questions?

Tags: discussion, identify, answers

When somebody ask a question with [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) tag, what is the right way for answering to question?

- How people should explain why they suggest this movie?
- Every answer should contain one movie?
- What if someone has two candidate movie? Should they add them in seperate answers?
- Questions should have only [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identify answers are expected to be as well done as the rest of the answers on the site.

As per example, I give my latest [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/8089/serial-killer-movie-where-cat-gets-murdered-on-doorstep/8090#8090) to an identify question.

Clean enough where I give the movie I believe it is, and explain with a short paragraph what led me to this conclusion.

Now lets say I had multiple conclusions for what movie it may be.  I'm honestly torn on what it should be for that.  Having multiple movie in the same answer would be ok, as long as they each are given the same amount of detail for your answer.  While posting separate ones will allow readers to more easily see which movie is actually the correct one.

Both ways have their flaws and advantages and we haven't really had a precedent set yet.

---

As far as what is not allowed, simply linking to an IMDB page *while not incorrect* will be met with comments from the mods about [**link only answers**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) and probably a few downvotes from like-minded users.

Answer (score 1):

1. As @TylerShads suggested, what led you to concluding specific movie should be explained. It can be small para or 3-4 lines. It will be better if you post poster, wiki link or imdb link to answer.
2. If posting multiple movie to identify-this-movie tag question, then ensure it should be in multiple answers. Describe what led you to that movie. And if it contradicts with anyone's opinion( may be you also ), why can't/ can that be a movie as OP describing.
3. Same as 2
4. It is a normal question. It can have multiple required tags as other questions. There is no any requirement for only have tag [identify-this-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie).